# upload files store 0 values

Tags: jquery, file-upload, uploadify

I create method for upload resume. it's not showing any error. when i open the file it shows empty.. there is no data..

**My controller**

```
       [HandleErrorWithAjaxFilter]
     public ActionResult UploadResume(HttpPostedFileBase FileData)
     {
         Stream fromStream = FileData.InputStream;
         Stream toStream = new FileStream(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Resumes/") + FileData.FileName, FileMode.Create);

         LoggedInCandidate.ResumeFileName = FileData.FileName;
         //_repository.Save();
         _userRepository.Save();

         return Json(new JsonActionResult
         {
             Success = true,
             Message = "Resume has been uploaded."
         });
         //return Json("Resume has been uploaded.");
     }
```

**View:**

```
 <input id="Resume" type="file" name="Resume" />
```

**Jquery:**

```
Models.Candidate.AddUploadResumeBehavior = function () {
$('#Resume').uploadify({
    'swf': root + '/Content/Flash/uploadify.swf',
    'uploader': root + '/Candidates/UploadResume',
    'cancelImg': root + '/Content/Images/uploadify-cancel.png',
    'auto': true,
    'multi': true,
    'fileDesc': 'Image Files',
    'fileExt': '*.jpg;*.png;*.gif;*.bmp;*.jpeg;*.doc',
    'queueSizeLimit': 90,
    'sizeLimit': 4000000,
    'buttonText': 'Upload Resume',
    'width': 200,
    'folder': root + '/uploads',
    'onComplete': function (event, queueID, fileObj, response, data) {
         Models.Candidate.ShowMessageBar("Resume has been uploaded.");
    },
    'onError': function (event, ID, fileObj, errorObj) {
        var msg;
        if (errorObj.type === "File Size")
            msg = 'File size cannot exceed 4MB';
        else
            msg = "An error occured while attempting to uploading resume."

         Models.Candidate.ShowMessageBar(msg);
        this.hide();
    }
});
```

};

Please find the issues and help me.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the fromStream in your code... You are simply creating a new file and closing it. hence the 0 byte length.

In .Net 4 you could do this:

```
Stream fromStream = FileData.InputStream;
Stream toStream = new FileStream(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Resumes/") + FileData.FileName, FileMode.Create);

// Actually upload the bytes!
fromStream.CopyTo(toStream);
```